# the object does not have the specified attribute error in python

Tags: python

I am new to python. The following is the code.

```
class simple:
    def __init__(self, str):
        print("inside the simple constructor")
        self.s = str


# two methods:

def show(self):
    print(self.s)

def showMsg(self, msg):
    print(msg + ":", self.show())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # create an object:
    x = simple("constructor argument")

    x.show()
    x.showMsg("A message")
```

After I run it, I got the

```
AttributeError: 'simple' object has no attribute 'show'
```

So, does anyone know what's going on here? 'show' is not an attribute, right? For my understanding, it should be a method. Does anyone understand what's going on here? Many thanks for your time and attention.

Comment: Indentation is necessary in Python. Make sure your instance methods are inside your class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to indent the methods to tell the interpreter that they are part of that class. Otherwise, you're simply creating standalone functions.

```
class simple:
    def __init__(self, str):
        print("inside the simple constructor")
        self.s = str

    # two methods:
    # note how they are indented

    def show(self):
        print(self.s)

    def showMsg(self, msg):
        print(msg + ":", self.show())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # create an object:
    x = simple("constructor argument")

    x.show()
    x.showMsg("A message")
```

Technically, if you wanted, you could make the unindented version work anyway by using `show(x)` instead of `x.show()`, but it'd be clearer to fix the indentation as above.